# MongoDB find() order child objects

Tags: mongodb

I know that I can use $orderBy when doing a find() on a collection.  But My collection contains other objects, how can I sort those objects?  For instance:

```
books: [{
  title: 'book 1',
  authors: [
     { name: 'jim' },
     { name: 'bob' },
  ]
}, {
  title: 'book 2',
  authors: [
     { name: 'steve' },
     { name: 'joe' },
  ]
}];
```

I want to do db.collections.find();  and have it return all books in order (which I know how to do using $orderBy, but I also want the authors sorted.

Comment: `$orderBy` works at the cursor level, so it will only change the order in which cursor returns the matching documents. Your best bet is to sort the array in each document when it is stored or updated - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to sort the documents at write time rather than read time.

As stated you're asking MongoDB to modify the documents before they reach your application. Mongo doesn't like to modify documents without a specific command. The main options for this are aggregation, map reduce and projection. None of these is a particularly good fit for your problem:

- Aggregation is probably more complex than you need, see the other answer for an option here.
- Map Reduce is like Aggregation, but more complicated.
- [Query-time Projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/) can filter the returned fields, but there are no sorting options.

Instead, store documents the way you want to retrieve them. When you write or update the documents initially, use the [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) array update operator on the `authors` array. The stored [BSON object](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) will preserve the ordering, so the array will be sorted when the document is retrieved.

This makes reads much simpler and faster than using the aggregation framework or map reduce.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you need. MongoDB returns the full documents, so the list of authors of all books would have to be compiled client-side or using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/). It can't be done using a simple query because it requires a projection before the sort operation.

Also, you'd probably want to have a distinct list of authors, otherwise some authors will appear in the list dozens of times.

Using the aggregation framework, you could do this:

```
db.books.aggregate(
   {"$unwind" : "$authors"},              // unwind the array
   {$group : {"_id" : "$authors.name"} }, // distinct
   {$sort : {"_id" : 1}});                // the actual sort
```

Comment: This isn't the actual schema I'm using, it's a simplified one to use for the question.  What I'm trying to do is return the collection of books, sorted by book title.  The collection also contains authors which I want sorted by name.  I can do this in javascript after I retrieve them but I wanted to know if there was a way to get them sorted with a query first.

Comment: Like I said, MongoDB returns documents and what you need would be two completely different lists - this can't be returned, because you'd have to get two cursors as a result. Then the question will be if using the aggregation framework or doing a client-side sort is faster, probably depends on your use case. Or do you only need the list of authors within a book sorted?